# Reading passwords stored in WildFly's Elytron credential store using Java?

Tags: java, security, wildfly, credentials, elytron

I have couple of application password stored in Wildfly 17.x credential stores. How to programmatically accessing the stored passwords from credential store?

This is how the credential store is created and password is stored in it.

```
/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=test:add(relative-to=jboss.server.data.dir, location=test.jceks, create=true,credential-reference={clear-text=storepass})

/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=test:add-alias(alias=keystorepw,secret-value=secret)
```

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276916 might help

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful. The problem was I didn't have the store with jceks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the store in a different extension instead of jceks. Once that is fixed, I can able to read the password from the store. Took a while to figure that out because WildFly did not complain while creating the store and all worked fine except reading it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

First forgive my writing in English. The best way i now it's using this code, with library Maven version 1.12.1.Final. Other libraries like the recent Alpha have errors with this code.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-elytron</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Method

```
public Password giveMeAPass(String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CredentialStoreException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    /*
     * Create a ProtectionParameter for access to the store.
     */
    Password storePassword = ClearPassword.createRaw(
            ClearPassword.ALGORITHM_CLEAR,
            "storepass".toCharArray());

    ProtectionParameter protectionParameter = new CredentialSourceProtectionParameter(
            IdentityCredentials.NONE.withCredential(
                    new PasswordCredential(storePassword)));

    Security.addProvider(elytronProvider);

    CredentialStore credentialStore = CredentialStore.getInstance(
            "KeyStoreCredentialStore", csProvider);
    // Configure and Initialise the CredentialStore
    String configPath = System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir");
    Map<String, String> configuration = new HashMap<>();
    
    String path = configPath + File.separator + "test.jceks";
    configuration.put("keyStoreType", "JCEKS");
    configuration.put("location", path);
    configuration.put("modifiable", "false");
    
    //Inicialize credentialStore
    credentialStore.initialize(configuration, protectionParameter);

    return credentialStore.retrieve(alias, PasswordCredential.class).getPassword();
}
```

This method is based on your credential store.

Comment: Thank you Biohazard for the code snippet. That's how I retrieved the password, the problem was using a different extension other than .jceks.

Comment: Hello. Function has compile problems. How do you get csProvider and  elytronProvider ? Are you injecting?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a complete example have a look at https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/blob/master/credential-store/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/examples/CredentialStoreExample.java
You can see there, that cs (named CREDENTIAL_STORE_PROVIDER there) and elytronProvider (named PASSWORD_PROVIDER there) are created by calling the apropriate constructor:
private static final Provider CREDENTIAL_STORE_PROVIDER = new WildFlyElytronCredentialStoreProvider();
private static final Provider PASSWORD_PROVIDER = new WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider();